# Compile data for the same id

Tags: r

I want to compile this data frame into a dataframe with only one row for each id, for each column value1, value2, value3, I want to take the value for A- B. I have tried to make a for loop to run over the ids, but I dont know how to continue, any advice? It would be really helpful with a function to run over many many columns, this is just an example of 3 columns. Thanks!

```
df <- data.frame(
   id=rep(1:5,each=2),
   trt = rep(c("A","B","A","B", "B","A", "B","A","A","B"),),
   value1 = sample(1:100,10),
   value2 = sample(1:100,10),
   value3 = sample(1:100,10),
   stringsAsFactors = F)
> df
   id trt value1 value2 value3
   1   A     98     64     91
   1   B     64     48     16
   2   A     26     31     87
   2   B     93     62     24
   3   B     32     37     71
   3   A     83      6     92
   4   B     82     68     36
   4   A     30      5     66
   5   A     87     29     48
   5   B     86     47     82
 
for (i in length(id)) {
     d <- df[df$id==i,]
     d$value1[d$trt=="A"]- d$value1[d$trt=="B"]
     print(i)
     }
```

Comment: Something like this `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with('value')), funs(.[trt == 'A'] - .[trt == 'B']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Data:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
    id=rep(1:5,each=2),
    trt = rep(c("A","B","A","B", "B","A", "B","A","A","B"),),
    value1 = sample(1:100,10),
    value2 = sample(1:100,10),
    value3 = sample(1:100,10),
    stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    gather(key, value, -trt, -id) %>% 
    mutate(value = if_else(trt == "B", -value, value)) %>% 
    group_by(id, key) %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    spread(key, value)
```

The point here is to, at first, transform with `gather` the dataframe into long form and put all your value in one column.

Seen that values with B must be subtracted, I set values with B as negative.

At that point I'm free to some all values by `id` and `key` (which is equal to the label `value1`, `value2`, `value3`).

I can return to the initial configuration of the dataframe with one column per each "value" with `spread`.

It doesn't matter how many "valueN" columns you have.

Comment: @EdoThanks for your solution! BUt what if the name of the columns are not value 1-3, it can be anything, do you have a suggestion for such situation?

Comment: In my code it's never written `value1`, `value2`, `value3`. Therefore it will work with whatever name of those columns. The only columns that need to be mentioned by name are `trt` and `id` in the line: `gather(key, value, -trt, -id)`; and `id` in line `group_by(id, key)`

Comment: `key` and `value` can be named whatever you prefer, as long as it's consistent. It's unrelated to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution with the `split/lapply/combine` strategy. See [Hadley Wickham's paper](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/plyr.pdf).

```
cols <- grep("value", names(df), value = TRUE)
sp <- split(df[c("trt", cols)], df$id)
res <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
  X <- sp[[i]][order(sp[[i]]$trt), ]
  Y <- X[1, cols] - X[2, cols]
  cbind(data.frame(id = names(sp)[i]), Y)
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)

res
#  id value1 value2 value3
#1  1     -6     63     28
#3  2    -32      8    -18
#6  3      6     -7    -63
#8  4    -67    -45      2
#9  5      1     20     45
```

Comment: If you do `x[1,] - x[2,]` it will fail when the order of A and B is reversed. Maybe sort first...Also I m pretty sure this can be achieved with only 1 `lapply`

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try the `data.table`package (using the same reproducible  data as @Edo):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = c("id","trt"))
df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(x) * -1), by = id, .SDcols = -2]
```

The result:

```
   id value1 value2 value3
1:  1    -16     17    -58
2:  2    -49     23    -55
3:  3     82     48    -18
4:  4    -23      9     13
5:  5    -18    -79     -7
```

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
library(data.table)
setorder(df, id, -trt)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, diff), by = id, .SDcols = -2]
```

Comment: Signs are inverted in your solution, aren't they?

Comment: @Edo Thx for spotting! Fixed it now :-)